# Contour integral involving Riemann sum

Tags: vector-analysis, riemann-sum

$\int_C{xdy-ydx}$; where $C$ is the curve $x=a\cos^3 t$, $y=a\cos^3t$
When I do whatever work for the working,i.e replacing the x,y,dx and dy in terms of t, I get

$3a^2\int{(\cos^2t \sin^2t})dt$.

How do I compute this integral.I would like to do the Riemann integral here, but I do not know the limits

For a Riemann sum

$S_n=\frac{b-a}{n}.∑_{k=0}^{k=n}.f\left(a+k\left(\frac{b-a}{n}\right)\right)$;

Would not my $∑_{k=0}^{k=n}f\left(a+k(\frac{b-a}{n})\right)$ become 0 here because sin and cos are complementary?

Comment: Can you check the definition of $C$ ?

Comment: I do not suss what you are trying to mean here.Is my working wrong? @ Tony Piccolo

Comment: Your integrand is *positive*. How could the integral become zero, then? Besides, computing such an integral directly from the Riemann sums is a highly non-trivial endeavour. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen, this question does not make much sense to me, that is why I posted this question.When I think in terms of a Riemann sum, I think I am going the wrong way. That is why I need some help here.

Comment: Well, to the first comment above (about checking $C$): As stated, you have $x=y$ on this curve. Is that correct? If so, you have translated the integral wrong, for surely, $x\,dy-y\,dx=0$ in that case by symmetry. My earlier comment overlooked this.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Osen, I am still a bit lost. Does that mean the integral is 0.The answer is  $\frac{3\pi^2}{a}$

Comment: Yes, the integral is zero *if* you have transcribed the problem correctly. Maybe it should have said $y=a\sin^3t$? Also, you haven't stated the range of the parameter $t$. My guess would be $[-\pi,\pi]$ or $[0,2\pi]$. Oh, and the answer should be proportional to $a^2$, so there is more apparent wrongness here.

Comment: If ever you find some light in this problem, Please do help. As soon as i get the correction of this work, I will let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from

$3a^2\int_0^{2\pi}{(\cos^2t \sin^2t})dt$

=$3a^2\int_0^{2\pi}{(\cos t \sin t})^2dt$

=$\frac{3a^2}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}{(\cos t \sin t})^2dt$

=$\frac{3a^2}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin 2t)^2dt$

$\cos 4t=1-2\sin^2 2t$
$\sin^2 2t=\frac{1}{2}(1-4\cos 4t)$

=$\frac{3a^2}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{2}(1-4\cos 4t)dt$

=$\frac{3a^2}{8}\int_0^{2\pi}(1-4\cos 4t)dt$

=$\frac{3a^2}{8}[t-\sin 4t]_0^{2\pi}$

=$\frac{3\pi a^2}{4}$

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen,Sorry for disturbing.It looks like I found an answer for this. I wanted to use a Riemannn integral for this, but never mind. I think it should be done this way.